# Trying to configure meteor with haml and coffeescript and getting error during meteor startup

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to install [this plug-in](https://npmjs.org/package/haml-coffee-meteor)

so I run:

`meteor create test`

`cd test`

`npm install haml-coffee-meteor`

`meteor`

and I get the following:

```
$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/test ]]]]]

No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Parse error - line 1, file /Users/xaxxon/test/node_modules/haml-coffee-meteor/spec/suites/templates/coffee/attributes.html
<div id='one'>
    at parseError (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/packages/templating/88d1cd8ec8579600ff26b8a0ed7bf23295887674/html_scanner.js:23:14)
    at Object.html_scanner.scan (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/packages/templating/88d1cd8ec8579600ff26b8a0ed7bf23295887674/html_scanner.js:36:15)
    at /Users/xaxxon/.meteor/packages/templating/88d1cd8ec8579600ff26b8a0ed7bf23295887674/package.js:44:32
    at _.extend.add_file (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/bundler.js:213:7)
    at self.api.add_files (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/bundler.js:126:16)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
    at self.api.add_files (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/bundler.js:125:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
    at Object.self.api.add_files (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/bundler.js:124:9)
    at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/packages.js:246:11)
    at _.extend.use (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/bundler.js:464:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/bundler.js:873:12)
    at /Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/run.js:697:26
    at exports.inFiber (/Users/xaxxon/.meteor/tools/cc18dfef9e/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12)

Please fix the problem and restart.
```

I don't really know what's going on, but if I don't install the haml-coffee-meteor package, it works as expected.  I think that maybe this package is trying to change how .html files are processed and this unit test is expecting traditional html to be parseable, but now the system is expecting haml and causes a test to break?  But I'm not even sure this is a unit test, so I really don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Blade](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/blade) which has a haml/jade-like syntax and which is easily downloadable from atmosphere.

Comment: how does atmosphere interact with meteor?  is it a node.js package manager? -- check that, what exactly is atmosphere?  All I see is some java servlet thing..

Comment: If you don't want to use meteorite/atmosphere, you can go to the github repository, download the project and put it on your `/packages/` directory. This is basically what meteorite/atmosphere does. It's a community maintained package manager - [see the doc](http://oortcloud.github.io/meteorite/).

Answer (score 0):

there are some work arounds as to where you can [install NPM packages directly in Meteor](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) . But the standard practice right now is to use [Meteorite](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/app)  for packages. I have not found an HTML preprocessor package that did not give me headaches with MEteor, though, so you might be better off sticking with handlebars. Best of luck!

Comment: after having worked with rails and haml for so long, I can't go back to writing out full HTML templates.. so painful :(